# How to loop an object inside an array in a sql procedure

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

types created :

```
create or replace TYPE BE_OBJ_TYP AS OBJECT
( 
BE_TRNID VARCHAR2(32),
BE_LOGTIMESTMP TIMESTAMP(6),
BE_SERVID INTEGER,
BE_MSGTYP VARCHAR2(30),
BE_REQID VARCHAR2(32),
BE_SRCSYS VARCHAR2(10),
BE_DSTSYS VARCHAR2(10),
BE_ENTEXT VARCHAR2(5),
BE_MSGDIR VARCHAR2(3),
BE_ERRCODE VARCHAR(10),
BE_MW_TRNS_ID VARCHAR2(32),
BE_REQ_TYP VARCHAR2(3),
BE_TOT_LAT DECIMAL,
BE_BACKEND_LAT DECIMAL,
VE_PAY_REF VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

and

```
create or replace type OBJTYPLIST as varray(10) of BE_OBJ_TYP
```

Th estored procedure is like :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST1PROC(TRANSID VARCHAR2 ,MSGTYP varchar2 ,TOTAL_LATENCY varchar2,aa in OBJTYPLIST)
AS
    BB BE_OBJ_TYP;
    ACount integer;
    SerId VARCHAR2(20);
    BESerId varchar(20);
    TS TIMESTAMP := current_timestamp ;

    BEGIN 

      select service_id into serid from service_metadata where service_name= msgtyp ;
      insert into ashutoshlog(transactionid,log_timestamp,service_id, messagetype, total_latency) 
      values(TRANSID,TS,SerId,MSGTYP,TOTAL_LATENCY );  

      commit;

        for BB in aa loop
        select be_service_id into beserid from backend_service_metadata where be_service_name=bb.BE_MSGTYP;
        dbms_output.put_line('Done till here');
        insert into soadetaillog(transactionid, service_id, be_service_id, latency) values(TRANSID,SerId,beserid,bb.BE_BACKEND_LAT);
        --insert into BE_SERVICE_DETAILS(messagetype,total_latency, versionnum) values (bb(1),bb(2),bb(3));
        dbms_output.put_line('Inserted');
        commit;
       end loop;  
    END;
```

I am not aware hoe to loop BB inside aa . means how to iterate through each object of the array 
. I have tried "for BB in aa " command here . But doesn't work . Can anyone please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

You have to `LOOP` it from *First Index* to *Total number of elements* in the Collection..

1. First Index can be referred as 1 directly.. or `COLLECTIONNAME.FIRST`
2. Total Number of elements may be referred using `COLLECTIONNAME.LAST`

And then every row in the collection has to be accessed by COLLECTIONNAME(INDEX).COLUMN_NAME

**Example:** `AA(INDEX).BE_TOT_LAT`

```
    for idx in 1..aa.COUNT loop
    select be_service_id into beserid from backend_service_metadata where be_service_name=aa(idx).BE_MSGTYP;
    dbms_output.put_line('Done till here');
    insert into soadetaillog(transactionid, service_id, be_service_id, latency) values(TRANSID,SerId,beserid,aa(idx).BE_BACKEND_LAT);
    --insert into BE_SERVICE_DETAILS(messagetype,total_latency, versionnum) values (aa(idx).BE_MSGTYP,aa(idx).BE_TOT_LAT,aa(idx).);
    dbms_output.put_line('Inserted');
    commit;
   end loop;
```